# Minecraft Bukkit Server - Only spawn zombies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I have a Minecraft Bukkit server and I want only zombies and friendly mobs to spawn. My version is 1.9.4 Craft Bukkit. I already tried plugins like Selective Spawns or Mob Spawn Settings but they don't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Greetings, new user! ( = Ahoj!)

Comment: Greetings, expirienced user! ( = Zdravím!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method #1**:

You can do this by auto-killing all hostile mobs that are not Zombies - Plug in Command blocks with these commands into a fast Redstone clock (or use the 1.9 Command Block fetures):

> /kill @e[type=Spider]
>
> /kill @e[type=Enderman]
>
> /kill @e[type=Creeper]
>
> /kill @e[type=Skeleton]
>
> /kill @e[type=CaveSpider]
>
> /kill @e[type=Witch]
>
> /kill @e[type=Slime]
>
> /kill @e[type=Guardian]

**Method #2** (the hardcore one):

When a non-Zombie hostile mob spawns, replace it with a Zombie - Again, on a fast RS clock plug Command blocks with these commands:

> /execute @e[type=Spider] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=Enderman] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=Creeper] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=Skeleton] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=CaveSpider] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=Witch] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=Slime] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~
>
> /execute @e[type=Guardian] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~

And, if **any** of these Command blocks has a positive output, trigger a Command block with this command (using a Comparator):

> /execute @e[type=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[type=!Zombie, r=2]

**Note**: the `r=2` is important, because if the mob would move when spawned and the command would be `r=1`, it wouldn't get killed, just moved - many mobs would spawn.

**Note**: You can redo this to the 1.9 Command block structure.

Comment: A potential problem with Method 2 is that it would kill any players within the radius. My suggestion is replace the kill command with a tag command (same target selectors) then you add one more command block with the kill command kill everyone with the tag except players.

Comment: @LethaIity yes, but what hostile mobs spawn **next** to players? :D

Comment: Mob Spawners Duh :P

Comment: @LethaIity I wanna see a Spider spawner spawn a Zombie :D You're free to edit my post; I will not reply any more comments to prevent flooding of this post :-)